# How to rotate valgrind logs while valgrind process is running

Tags: valgrind

How can i rotate the valgrind logs on my linux system while the valgrind process is running as the valgrind logs as when valgrind logs become greater than 2 GB it stops logging and it have to kill the valgrind process, clean the logs and then restart the valgrind process. What i meant is dynamic cleaning of logs. If i clean the log , the next moment it again fills to original while valgrind is running.

Please note: my process spwans children on new connections and hence the logs grows quite fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to use the valgrind option
--log-socket=ipaddr:port  log messages to socket ipaddr:port

Then in another window, you read the output of all processes
using

valgrind-listener port-number

You can then have the output of valgrind-listener split in small files
e.g. using

```
valgrind-listener ... args ... | split
```

which will generate small files.

Comment: Thanks..but i am able to write/enhance a listener code (template provided by built in packages) and then redirect to small sized files.